# Joomla 3.0 Administrator Panel

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I can't access to Joomla 3.0 on local host, I have changed the password to admin password in database, but when I tried to login Joomla says:

> Warning : Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
Access you phpmyadmin -> go to #__users table choose your admin user name.
Then update your password with this
08af319cdddbcac8d2949042a416ac61:447pZnWzKdAQ81R9kX4xNiPfZTM5JOwE
```

The above encrypted value is the password of 123456.

first you just update password in the DB then you will get access to admin panel. There you can change your admin user password. Users->users manager->edit

Hope this will works..

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this message this it's pretty obvious that your username and/or password do not match. You say you have changed the admin password in the database but you do realise that passwords are encrypted so entering a standard word will not work.

Here are some steps that will get you access again.

1. Set up another fresh copy of Joomla in a new folder
2. Once you have set up your account for the new copy of Joomla, go into phpMyAdmin and copy the encrypted password from the `#__users` table.
3. List item Not go to the `#__users` table from your previous copy of Joomla and paste the encrypted password in there.

**Note:** Make sure both copies of Joomla are the same version

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your time, @Lodder What I mean by change password I have changed it with encrypted admin "encrypted "7e1ea5c159f2911b6e3e3599bd5680a1:SmLSS4zkVJLppONbPR4XJ6pENxGH8Fzl", but it did not work :(

Comment: Like I said, try what I have suggested and then you can change your password to whatever you like in the backend once you have reset it. Either do this, or try what @Jobin Jose has suggested ;)